# Creating new column in Hive based on previous value of another column

Tags: hive, window-functions

I have data that looks like this:

```
Status Order
NULL   1
NULL   2
1      3
NULL   4
NULL   5
0      6
NULL   7
NULL   8
NULL   9
1      10
```

I am trying to add a new column that fills in the nulls with the previous number, such as:

```
Status     New
NULL       NULL
NULL       NULL
1          1
NULL       1
NULL       1
0          0
NULL       0
NULL       0
NULL       0
1          1
```

I am using hive, and do have access to pyspark, but was trying to solve through SQL if possible. I have looked into window functions (Rank, Dense_rank, Row_number, Lag, Lead). Any suggestions?

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* columns.  You need a column to specify the ordering.

Comment: I apologize for not including it, but there is a column that signals order. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are equivalence groups.  Then you can use window functions to fill in the data.  A group can be defined as the number of non-null values up to an including a given value.

*This assumes that you have a column that specifies the ordering.*

So:

```
select t.*, max(status) over (partition by grp) as new_status
from (select t.*, count(status) over (order by ?) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Brilliant! It works, now I have to dissect why it works. Thanks again.